# remove pixels from image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, resize

all!

I am trying to load up in image in XCode ios and with the push of a button do two things:

- delete and entire vertical row of pixels from an image
- Resize that image width to 1 pixel smaller and save

Any tips on these two procedures would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Copy two areas out of the image and create a new image out of it. One of the two areas misses 1 vertical line.

Croping and copying images is described all over StackOverflow.

Comment: I guess that could work. Eventually I'd like to evolve it to where the removed line isn't vertical, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it